# Game to teach kids numbers and vectors along x and y axes and programming

Tags: programming, game, educational, game-development, children

I am looking for a simple app, which I think would be good for five to eight year olds, to learn a little bit about numbers and programming.

On the top left, some icons which can be scrolled and dragged to the intersection points of a grid, placed on the bottom left, with a turtle at the origin.

On the top right:

a plus or minus button next to a number selection button / scrollable integer widget, for movements of a turtle along the x axis.

Another set for y moments.

The turtle is placed on at the origin.

At the bottom right:

You move the turtle, by programming a list of (x,0) and (0,y) vectors, by clicking on the add vector button on the top right, and when the list is complete, you click on the Go button at the bottom of the list, for the turtle to go eat the stuff.

If the turtle doesn't eat all items (it tries to eat each time it stops), then you must reprogram the list. You can select to show clues (the vectors), or not show them, while you program the turtle.

Thanks.